# How do I make the Explorer bread crumb trail always show the full path?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I like the bread crumbs in Windows Explorer. They are more like what I'm used to from Ubuntu at home, but when I'm at work I am forced to use Windows.

What bothers me is when the bread crumb trail starts with `Libraries` (for example when I open `Documents`), or when I open a folder from a search result, and the trail starts with `Search Results in [Search location]`.

How do I remove this behaviour and make the bread crumb trail actually show me where I am?

---

UPDATE:

Recently this has bothered me enough that I felt the need to revisit it. As my comment to the below answer by Amer is relevant I decided to copy it up here to elaborate.

A search result results in a path like: `search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Devel%20(D%3A)&crumb=System.Gener??ic.String%3Adump&crumb=location:D%3A%5C\dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`. The breadcrumbs show here `Search Results in Devel (D:)` > `dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`. I need the full path for `dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`. Currently I do this by entering `explorer` in the address bar, and pressing `[Enter]`.

I have found a work-around for the `Libraries` issue (just fold out e.g. `Documents` in the sidebar and choose the exact location), but would still like the breadcrumbs to show the actual path all the time.

Comment: It would also be nice if someone would upvote me enough to be able to at least give Amer an upvote for his effort in trying to answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the bread crumb *is* showing you exactly where you are.

In Windows 7, the "Library" concept was introduced, which is like a folder for your folders or a meta-folder if you will. You can add folders from all over your PC and across networks to a library so that you can easily access all the contents through one click.

Your `Documents` library contains the traditional `My Documents` and most likely a folder called `Public Documents` (though I have seen one build of Windows 7 without `Public Documents`). By default, the `My Documents` folder is set as the `save location`. Which basically means when creating in, saving to, or copying to the `Documents` library, the file will be saved in the `My Documents` folder.

You'll notice you can expand the `Documents` library in Windows Explorer by clicking on the arrow to its left. There it will list the actual folders in the library. The one you are concerned with, if I am not mistaken, is `My Documents`.

So when you click on `Documents` you are actually seeing the contents of all the folders in the `Documents` library, which for you is most likely `My Documents` and `Public Documents`. But `Public Documents` is probably empty.

If you really want to see the bread crumb for `My Documents` you need to access `My Documents` directly and not through the `Documents` library.

Now about `Search Results`. I am not quite how would a bread crumb could even work here. `Search Results` don't really exist anywhere (well they do but I don't see the point of accessing them via bread crumb). `Search Results` were created then and there when you performed a search, so you are kind of at the root of the trail.

Comment: A search result results in a path like: `search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Devel%20(D%3A)&crumb=System.Generic.String%3Adump&crumb=location:D%3A%5C\dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`.
The breadcrumbs show here `Search Results in Devel (D:) > dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`. I need the full path for `dump_2013-04-23_09-27-15`. Currently I do this by entering `explorer .` in the address bar.

Comment: Alright, I get what you mean with Search Results now. You search for something and go into a folder found in the search results and the problem occurs. Well for that, all I can suggest right now is to right click the folder you want to go into and choose `Open folder location` (near the bottom). This will open the folder with the full path.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, anything in one of these "crummy" locations can be opened by right clicking then clicking *Open File/Folder Location*. If you want it in another window then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click

It's far from ideal but it works. Welcome to Microsoft.

Comment: This is weird.  When I do this, the path is still prefixed with "Search results in..." but if I click on the address bar, the actual path is shown (eg: it starts with "C:\").  This doesn't occur if I click on the address bar of the original window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another "solution".  Right click on the file/folder and select properties.  Then in the General tab you can find a "Location" field that you can copy.

[image]

Comment: I know this, but it is slow and bothersome. Sorry :)

Comment: @beruic Absolutely, I agree.